# Will replacing 'to' with 2 or 'for' with 4 improve my site's PageRank

Tags: seo, pagerank, optimization

Is it true that replacing words such as "to" and "for" with numbers (2 and 4 respectively) help increase my website's PageRank.

Is it a useful SEO technique and if so why does it work?

Comment: Hmm L337 5P34|< as SEO? 4 teh awesomes! Most of the people searching for your site don't search in leet speak though, so no.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you get any seo benefits from this, which I doubt (see John Conde's Answer), it will not be enough to make up for the fact that you have bad unprofessional content littered with "2s" and "4s".

Answer (score 6):

No, it's not true. Why should it? How does that improve the content or its relevancy?

Comment: Yet Google gives some hefty return for "4 the love of god", including scripture references with "for" being in the relevent search returns. I think the world's gone mad... I guess I can see someone mistaking Google cross referencing 4 and for as a snake oil boost.

Comment: You have to love the power of anchor text

Comment: @FiascoLabs Google is obviously treating the two keywords `4` and `for` equally.