# SEO and Spelling mistakes in keyword

Tags: seo, domains, keywords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will replacing 'to' with 2 or 'for' with 4 improve my site's PageRank](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25028/will-replacing-to-with-2-or-for-with-4-improve-my-sites-pagerank)

I am about to register a domain name (suppose) **someone.com** (with proper spelling), in mind targeting the keyword "**SOMEONE**". But then I discovered on 'google keyword research tool' that not this but a typo "**SOME1**" *seems to be more popular* and people search this significantly more often than the proper keyword. And luckily someone.com and some1.com both are available.

I understand that I can register both the domains, but I don't know on which should I keep my website and redirect the other one. Should I make the typo "some1.com" my base site? But that's a *typo*.

P.S., my site has a totally relevant content and not just keyword targeted worthless site.

What do you guys suggest? I am confused. How would that affect my SEO ranking??

EDIT:
Because the competition for the keyword I am targeting is fairly low, I think nevertheless whatever domain I choose, it will appear on the search engine first page.

Answer (score 2):

I would first find out if it's a famous name or brand which is trademarked or famous enough that it doesn't have to be trademarked. You may be setting your self up to receive a DMCA notice.

To answer your question I would use the domain which spelled the name correctly and had the highest search volume. The second site using say some1 I would build with relevant content for using the misspelling so that domain would become authoritive for the misspelling.

I suspect you're going to try and monetize from the domains. I would calculate the time to rank high enough to get a return. Are you going to be making a few cents < .10 per click? Or a small % of commission on some other affiliate network? How soon before you recover your $20 in registration fees and ~$50 in hosting? Will it take months or years to start earning a profit?

Comment: I'd also go with the first one.  For mainly all the same reasons as stated above (maybe some1 is trademarked).  Just remember you state that your site has totally relevant content I'm assuming to "someone" so I would recommend using the proper spelling.

Answer (score 1):

You also have to consider branding as well, which one of the names are you going to use to market your site, many forms require a site name along with the web address.